# How would I know what the JQuery function parameters are?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm making a table sortable and I came across this bit of code at http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable/

```
// Return a helper with preserved width of cells
var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
    ui.children().each(function() {
        $(this).width($(this).width());
    });
    return ui;
};

$("#sort tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelper
}).disableSelection();
```

How did the person who wrote this know what e and ui are so as to use them for the function parameters? Why does it return ui?

Comment: They read the documentation for the sortable function. That's the standard way of finding how what values to pass to an API.

Comment: I looked at it, but I don't see where those parameters come from.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [documentation for the helper option](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper) on the jQuery UI sortable you'll see that it says:

> The function receives the event and the element being sorted.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that's what was being talked about there. Thanks

Comment: This really opens up a lot of understanding. Thanks again!